# Jquery custom written selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to solve the following problem all sorts of ways today.  I've spent hours on it and I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

The basic problem is this:  I have a bunch of JavaScript logic going on to figure out if the following variables should be a 1 or 0.

```
1)active
2)alternative
3)classic
4)vintage
etc....
```

and all these variables act essentially as filters in my design.  I need them to determine whether a product should be displayed or not.  So once these values are determined, I want to display product styles accordingly (or hide product styles) by appending or removing a CSS class (let's call it `.style`) .  Each product has 1 or multiple of the filters attached to it.  So like a pair of shoes might be classic AND alternative, in which case a 1 in either classic OR alternative variables should cause the shoes to display with the style.

What's the best way to do this display aspect?  I was thinking of writing a custom selector but I'm having a very hard time figuring out how to write it.

Something like...

```
if($(".divProducts").hasClass(active) || $(".divProducts").hasClass(alternative) || etc..)
{
 ....?
}
```

but I don't get very far this way because first of all, even if the IF statement clause parses correctly, I won't know which product actually returned a 1 in alternative or active or any of the other filters.

This is really hard to explain.

**TLDR; Basically I need this:**

If ANY of the elements in some div container have ANY of the filters that are of value 1, apply `.style` to each of those elements.

Help would be hugely appreciated as this is part of a project due tomorrow actually... I didn't expect to have such a hard time with it :\

By the way, the products keep track of filters with classes.  So for example
shoes product->

```
<div class="blah blah vintageFilter blah blah">...</div>
```

I want to apply `.style` class to this div IF vintage variable is 1.  Make sense?

Comment: please share the markup and the desired output

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach will be more readable and say more managable

```
 switch(true) {

 case $('.divProducts').hasClass(active) :
     // some action
 break;

 case $(".divProducts").hasClass(alternative) :
    // some action
 break;

 default :
 //some action

}
```

Comment: While this will work, I disagree that it's readable. Programmers are mostly used to `switch` statements matching an expression to a sequence of literals (because many languages require `case` to be followed by a literal), not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
// First clear the .style class from everything
$('.divProducts').removeClass('style');
// Then add it to the selected items
$('.divProducts.active, .divProducts.alternative').addClass('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you had included some HTML, but since you didn't I'm going to assume that you have something that looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="active" />Active</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="alternative" />Alternative</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="classic" />Classic</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="vintage" />Vintage</label>
</fieldset>
<div id="result">You picked: <span id="selection"><span></div>
<div class="products">
    <div class="vintage classic">Vintage and Classic</div>
    <div class="vintage">Vintage</div>
    <div class="classic">Classic</div>
    <div class="classic alternative">Alternative and Classic</div>
    <div class="alternative">Vintage and Classic</div>
</div>
```

The solution is simple and you don't even need a conditional. The way I would accomplish it is with the following JavaScript:

**JavaScript**

```
$("input[name='type']")
    .on("click", function()
        {
            // Clear result showing state
            $("#result").removeAttr("class");

            // Get selected value
            var typeVal = $(this).attr("value");
            $("#result").addClass(typeVal);
            $("#selection").text(typeVal);

            // Remove match class
            $(".products div").removeClass("match");

            // Show matching products and add match class
            $(".products ." + typeVal).addClass("match");
        });
```

With this CSS:

**CSS**

```
.active { color: #f00; }
.alternative { color: #0f0; }
.classic { color: #00f; }
.vintage { color: #999; }
.match { background: #ccc; }
```

Here's a link to the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XQVet/3/

**Update:** Changed it so that elements wouldn't disappear.